# Convert "Xh Xm" string into integer

Tags: javascript, string, integer

Simply put I have the following string `"105h 28m"`.

Using JavaScript, I'd like to convert it into an integer (milliseconds?) which is then easier to manipulate later.

Comment: What is the hard part? Where have you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string and use `parseInt` to convert string to number:

```js
var time = "105h 28m";
function toMiliseconds(t){
  t = t.split(/ +/);
  return parseInt(t[0])*60*60*1000  //convert hour to milliseconds
          + parseInt(t[1])*60*1000; //convert minitues to milliseconds
}
console.log(toMiliseconds(time));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use a regular expression to get the value of hours and minutes:

```js
let [, hours, minutes] = "105h 28m".match(/(\d+)h\s(\d+)m/);

let milliseconds = (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60) * 1000;

console.log(milliseconds); // 379680000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can pass your string and it'll convert that to milliseconds. I've also covered the `sec` into milliseconds.

```js
const convertToMilliseconds = (time) => {
  return time.split(" ").reduce((milliseconds, time) => {
    if(time.slice(-1) === 'h') {
        milliseconds += (+time.slice(0, -1) * 3600000);
    } else if(time.slice(-1) === 'm') {
        milliseconds += (+time.slice(0, -1) * 60000);
    } else {
        milliseconds += (+time.slice(0, -1) * 10000);
    }
    return milliseconds;
  }, 0)
}
let time = "105h 28m";

const milliseconds = convertToMilliseconds(time);

console.log(milliseconds);
```